# php exec not working on mamp

Tags: php, macos, unity-game-engine, exec, mamp

I'm trying to launch an executable myapp made with unity by using the following code in php, but I'm getting errors.

```
<?php
echo "yo";
echo exec('whoami',$output,$retval);
echo $retval;
echo exec('myapp.app',$output,$retval);
echo $retval;
echo exec('/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myapp.app/',$output,$retval);
echo $retval;
?>
```

The result is yodan127127.
127 I looked up in error codes means procedure not found.

I have also commented out some lines in Applications/Mamp/Library/bin/envvars_ 
which was recommended in other posts.

I have put the myapp.app in several directories 
htdocs,bin,cgi-bin, but gives the same error.

```
#if test "x$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH" != "x" ; then
#  DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"
#else
#  DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib"
#fi
#export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
#
```

Comment: The path to your binary should be `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myapp.app/Contents/MacOS/myapp`. `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myapp.app/` is just a directory.

Comment: Cool. I would have never figured that out. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to point `exec` to the binary, and not the container for it.

The `.app` is just a container directory that has an internal structure, the binary is somewhere in a path that should look like `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myapp.app/Contents/MacOS/myapp`. The precise location of the binary is in the `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myapp.app/info.plist` file. You can right click on the app and select show package contents to view the structure.

But the easiest way to run the app is to open it with the `open` command:

```
open '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myapp.app/'
```

It should be runnable from php as an argument to `exec`.

Answer (score -1):

Excel commend are used in PHP so this are required installation on server,commends like image magick etc. then you use exec() function.

Comment: The dump from echo clearly states that he has the `exec` function (and that his username is dan). Also, the [php manual for exec](http://php.net/manual/en/exec.installation.php) says that "There is no installation needed to use these functions; they are part of the PHP core."